# Include header and put index inside header html

Tags: php, html, css

I have a html header included with php include function however my context inside the index "Hi, World! is showing underneath my included header and not inside a html div from the header itself where I want. My screenshots:

The problem:
[image: Problem]

What I want:
[image: what i want]

So what i would like is the that my index:

```
<body>
<?php include('header.php'); ?>
<div >
    <h3>Hi, <span class="">World!</span>
    </h3>
</div> 
</body>
```

shows inside the following div from my header.php:

```
<div class="content"> </div>
```

Comment: You're going to have to rethink how you have everything laid out. The content will go above the Hi World because of the opening/closing divs. The content div will be closed before it gets to the one in your index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was fixed by removing one `</div>` in this way the content is still opened to html further in an other document.